# Clicking on non-selectable text selects selectable text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tested on chrome (latest version) for Samsung (latest version of Android): if I click on a selectable text in my html page and then click on non-selectable text it is as if I clicked again on the selectable one. The selectable text is then selected and deselected each time I click on the non-selectable one. This behavior doesn't happen on pc and, as I was told, not even on ios. I don't know if it's a feature of Android or only Samsung phones, but I definitely need to avoid this behavior.

Test this snippet on android to understand the problem:

```html
<p style="user-select: none;">By clicking here the text below will be selected and deselected<p>
<br>
<p>Select this text and then the one above this to understand the problem</p>
```

Update: I partially fixed the bug by adding the following code

```
unselectableText.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that in doing so the selected text is not deselected on click (as would happen with a click anywhere on the screen).

Comment: I tried this on my own phone (Motorola moto g8 running Android 11) on the most recent version of chrome and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: I think it's definitely a problem with Samsung devices. I attempted to fix using a preventDefault and was partially successful. Unfortunately this won't let me deselect the text...so I tried a removeAllRanges in addition. This comes close to the solution, but it doesn't close the menu for the selected text

Answer (score 1):

```
unselectableText.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
  window.getSelection()?.collapseToEnd();
});
```

It's definitely what I was looking for! Now the bug has been removed and the text is deselected with a click on my navbar.